# (ctypes)msvcrt.printf and print in python

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, ctypes

I was learning a bit about using the printf function using msvcrt.dll , ctypes in python 2.7 .
 I observed that when using the msvcrt.printf("x") and usual python print("y") function, "y" gets printed before "x" eventhough print("y") statement is put after the msvcret.printf("x") . Can anyone explain why this is happening?

This is my code:

```
from ctypes import *

msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
msvcrt.printf("hello world!")

print("abcd")
```

output :

```
abcd
hello world
```

Comment: I assume the stdout buffer is not flushed unless you do it explicitly after printf.

Answer (score 0):

This code runs correctly under my environment and the result is here:

[image: Result]